# How to enable batch mode via MAVEN_OPTS or .mavenrc?

Tags: maven, terminal, devops

How can I enable batch mode (i.e disable color output) with either MAVEN_OPTS or .mavenrc?

I cannot pass `--batch-mode` directly to `mvn`, because another processes starts it, and my part is responsible only for capturing logs. I cannot pipe output though another programm either.

So far I've tried:
`-Dstyle.color=never`
`-Dmaven.color=false`.
Neither worked.

Comment: Writing logs to a file via `mvn -l logfile.txt` ? Giving `--batch-mode` is the other option...

Comment: @khmarbaise I cannot control how maven is being called, only the enviroment from which it's being called.

Comment: Simple answer then. Not possible via MAVEN_OPTS or `.mavenrc` ... Use `--batch-mode` or `-l logfile.. ` ...The other process should be changed simply... to solve the problem... The posting here / discussion etc. took more time than the simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get rid of the color, then you can do it with Java system properties via the [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) environment variable even if you don't have control over the `mvn` command line:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dstyle.color=never"
```

You can see how [Maven uses this property by looking at the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/df67c00fba25a52e39fa43021b52de8a25b6e999/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java#L507-L525).

I recognize that you claim you've tried `-Dstyle.color=never` in some other fashion but perhaps this particular usage will get you what you want.

Comment: -Dstyle.color seems to only work when specified by command line arguments. Files as a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7031

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug as user properties in Maven are not System properties.  I had thought that supplying them as system properties via `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` would do the trick, but I guess not.